# p-values based on exact null distribution

Tags: python, statsmodels, p-value

I have two arrays. One is array of real observed values -> cluster sizes. Other is array of cluster sizes computed by monte-carlo simulation, so mine exact null distribution. I would like to transform real observed values in to p-values, so I can later compute FDR corrected p-values. I can do it element by element, but there should be a better way

Comment: something like `1 - numpy.searchsorted(np.sort(null), observed) / len(observed)` will give you the fraction of observations in the null that are larger than the observed values (use `side` for strict or weak inequality)

Answer (score 1):

check out the following tests.  Hope it helpful.
[Tukey's range test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test) or 
Duncan's new multiple range test

And more information can be found in [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).

unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to put in more links...

Comment: you misunderstood my question. What I want to do is to find p-value for every number from mine observation against the null distribution. So lets say I have a cluster of size 25, I will sort the null distribution values and find that 95 percent of them is lower then 25 and 5 percent is bigger, therefore p-value of 25 is 0.05. I would like to do that for all the observation, so I can then use statsmodel to correct it